# Как с помощью python3 пробежаться по вордовскому документу и поменять шрифты?

Tags: python, ms-word

Как с помощью питона пробежаться по вордовскому файлу и поменять шрифты в буквах в рандомном порядке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать готовую библиотеку, например, вот эту:

https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Вы можете значительно удучшить ответ, приведя небольшой пример и заменив ссылку на рабочую ;)